# Writing a css for text padding

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm making a website with elementor pro and in a page im using an element named advanced search
This element takes an input from a user and search the site
The css selector of this element is .eael-advanced-search
I want to add an offset to the input that user gives in the live site in the input box of this element but can't find the custom css

I already tried this but didn't work:

```
.eael-advanced-search input[type="text"] {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't mean anything. What about this "didn't work"? What does the HTML of your element look like?

Comment: the outer HTML is :
'''
<input type="text" placeholder="رشته مورد نظر خودتون رو سرچ کنید" class="eael-advanced-search" autocomplete="off" name="eael_advanced_search">
'''

The URL is https://drkzmi.com/%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B6%DB%8C/
And i want to change the search bar there

Comment: Did you mean to add `padding-right` to the input field?

Comment: Yes. Right padding to the input field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* It selects input containing a class ".eael-advanced-search" */
.eael-advanced-search{
    padding-right: 20px !important;
}
```

The way you were trying was looking for input inside the class ".eael-advanced-search"

A better approach will be to use this one because it is the actual selector for styling so you don't have to use `!important` to overwrite anything:

```
.eael-advanced-search-widget .eael-advanced-search-form.eael-advanced-search-form-style-1 .eael-advanced-search-wrap .eael-advanced-search{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this but I just want to change the input part  `Element (input.eael-advanced-search) is over qualified, just use .eael-advanced-search without element name`

Comment: @ARASH You can either use the 2nd option (better) or the first one. Now it will work.